# Any Regex Library for gcc 4.8

Tags: c++, regex, gcc4.8

I need to used Regex in my application. I was using Boost(Regex) but that has been supported by gcc 4.9. Similarly standard Regex library is compatible with onle gcc version >= 4.9. 
Is there any c++ Regex library that is compatible with gcc 4.8.5.
Note: I can't update gcc version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with gcc 4.9 vs gcc 6.3 (after upgrading to Debian Stretch from Jessie) in a multithreaded program that used `std::shared_ptr`. The problem was that gcc 4.9 didn't support `std::atomic_load`, which was a problem for multithreading.

So, the solution is simple: Since boost and std share (almost) the same interface, you could create a header file that [detects](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) the compiler version. If it's 4.9 or higher, then use std regex, otherwise, use boost regex:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#if __GNUC__ > 4 || \
    (__GNUC__ == 4 && (__GNUC_MINOR__ > 9 || \
                       (__GNUC_MINOR__ == 9 && \
                        __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ > 0))
#include <regex>
#define Regex std::regex
#else
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#define Regex boost::regex
#endif
#endif
```

And where you need regex, use this file, and the compiler will automatically do all the selection for you. And use the new defines that you create up there to call regex functions and objects.